# How to end http session when the browser is closed in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf

Is changing the "session-timeout" param in web.xml the only way to end a user's session without clicking on the Logout button?

Is there any other way to log a person out when he closes the browser?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To log a person out when the browser is closed would require a Javascript function to make an ajax request.

This really is not possible, because if you execute a javascript function for `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` then the script will execute every time you navigate away from the page as well.

Bottom line is that even if you could figure out a way to do this, it is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have control over the user's browser, you can't force it to send anything to you to signal that the client has closed the browser.

Besides, I think one of the main purpose of cookies is that they allow users to get instant access to the web's service without having to log in again & again. A client may close his Facebook window and open it again in 5 minute. How can we know when he's really closing his Facebook to delete the cookies?